# Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++ (for date convert)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need regexp for replace date format PostgreSQL to Mysql

From:

```
2011-02-10 18:33:57.29674+02
```

To:

```
2011-02-10 18:33:57
```

please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Ctrl + H.. select Regex Expression.

Find pattern : `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{5}\+\d{2}`

Replace : `\1`

Enter! :D